# How to implement locking mechanism for mysql table row to avoide race condition?

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php
    $time=getdate();
    $time['month'];
    $temp_time=$time['month']." ".$time['year'];
    $q="SELECT * FROM websiteviews ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $r=mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
    if($temp_time==$r['timespan']){
        $count=$r['view']+1;
        $q="UPDATE websiteviews SET view='".$count."' WHERE id='".$r['id']."'";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        echo mysqli_error($dbc);
    }
    ?>
```

Hi friends I am updating page views of my website every time webpage is loaded 
this piece of code is placed on the top of the page now my question is this mechanism can cause race condition i want to lock my row until it is updated please help with mysql query to lock particular row until it is updated

Comment: You should really use prepared statements if you use mysqli

Comment: What is the table type?

Comment: table type is utf-8 on innoDB

Comment: @user3787783 Just for clarification `utf-8` is a [`Character Set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-general.html), not a table type, it is only applied to those columns which are storing character data. [`Storage Engine`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/storage-engines.html) handles how the data stored (persisted). The `Storage Engine` could be specified by the `ENGINE` or `TYPE` keyword. The `TYPE` keyword is supported for backward compatibility. (From version `3.23.0` to `4.0.18` only the `TYPE` keyword was available. The `TYPE` keyword is now deprecated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud not select then update the record you want to update.

```
UPDATE
  websiteviews
SET
  view = view+1
WHERE
  -- Assuming 'timespan' is a varchar column and the stored format is 'MM YYYY'
  timespan = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m %Y')
```

The above query updates the record in one step, so the race condition could be handled by the DBMS. Possibly you should change the `WHERE` condition to match to your requirements.

If the column `view` is nullable, then change the `SET` part to `view = COALESCE(view, 0)+1`

**Storage engines**

In MySQL the tables could be stored via different storage engines and all engines has different support of locking (if any).

Additional resource: [About locking when InnoDB is the storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-locking.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need use transaction locking but your tables need to use engine that supports transactions like InnoDB

You can read more on

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-restrictions.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transactions to solve the race condition, something like below:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT view, id FROM websiteviews ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;

#id obtained from previous step
#view obtained from previous step
UPDATE websiteviews SET `view`=<view>+1 WHERE id= <id>;
COMMIT;
```

NOTE: Take note of the "FOR UPDATE" clause used with select statement.